# Factorization of $x^n - x$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, prime-factorization

While studying about the galois field $GF(2)[x]$, i wanted to find out whether a given polynomial is primitive or not. To do that i need to factor this term:

$x^8 - x$.

I got the only solution that it is equals to $x(x−1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$ but no explaination how to do that.

How can i factor the expression : $x^8 - x$ to the corresponding polynomials product?What is the procedure?

Comment: good first step: $$x^n-x=x(x^{n-1}-1)$$

Comment: First step i also know but the problem is from $x^n -1 $.

Comment: What is "the" Galois field? You must have a particular one in mind; otherwise that factorization might not work.

Answer (score 1):

Factor out the $x$, then $x - 1$. The roots of the quotient occur in conjugate pairs.  Each pair yields up an irreducible (over the reals) quadratic.

Comment: and there’s a linear term $x - 1$